# Why doesn't a compareTo BigInteger while loop exit?

Tags: java, while-loop, biginteger

I have this method that is stuck in a while loop, I print the boolean value of the condition in the method itself and it does eventually get to be false but it will not exit the cycle.

```
    public static boolean isPalindrome(BigInteger num) {
         BigInteger invertedNum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
         BigInteger auxNum = num;

         while (auxNum.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) != 0) {
             invertedNum = invertedNum.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10)).add(auxNum.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10)));
             auxNum = auxNum.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
             System.out.println(auxNum.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) != 0);
    }

    return invertedNum == num;
}
```

Comment: BTW you need to use `compareTo` not `==` for comparison.

Comment: I use compareTo to compare the BigInt to 0, it will either return -1, 0 or 1, then I compare that value to 0 is that not right?

Comment: For me it prints false and exists the loop. Perhaps the problem is your method always returns `false`.

Comment: That is right, Try `return invertedNum.compareTo(num) == 0` or `return invertedNum.equals(num);`

Comment: you can also use `equals(BigInteger.ZERO)` if you only want to know if the number is (or not) zero. (There is also no need for `BigInteger.valueOf(10)`, better use `BigInteger.TEN` IMHO)

Answer (score 3):

I ran your code and it works fine; the while loops exits.

Your code does have 2 bugs in it:

- in the `.add(auxNum.divide)` call I assume you want `mod` instead.
- you can't compare bigints with `==`. You must use `.equals` (in the while loop you use `.compareTo` which works fine, but `.equals` is more readable, in that it correctly expresses what you're trying to accomplish. You're comparing with == at the very end, in the `return` statement.

Applying those 2 fixes, your code correctly returns true for palindromic (in decimal) numbers, and false otherwise.